# Storing password in variable for session duration

Tags: java, security, encryption, passwords

I'm planning on storing a plaintext password in memory for the duration of a session and would like to get some feedback on how insecure this would be. The reason for storing the password is that it will be used multiple times during a session to both encrypt and decrypt data in the background when the user of the application performs certain actions. I assume it would be safer to get the user to enter the password each time but this would lead to a very poor user experience so I'm trying to come up with a solution that is as secure as possible without irritating users.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the password to encrypt/decrypt the data directly, you should derive a key from the password (see PBKDF2). This derived key that is used for encryption/decryption is safer to have stored in memory for extended periods of time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Correct me if I'm wrong but I assume what you're suggesting is something like this: the user supplies their password, a key is then derived from this password and this key is stored in memory for the duration of the session and used to encrypt and decrypt any data. Just one question I have about this - would an attacker not be able to decrypt any encrypted data if they obtained the derived key? Thanks for your help!

Comment: *"This derived key that is used for encryption/decryption is safer to have stored in memory for extended periods of time."* - Can you explain why exactly this would be safer? I don't think it is.

Comment: Yes they would be able to decrypt/encrypt the data if they obtained the derived key, but your users would be thankful that their actual passwords were not exposed. Storing decryption keys in memory is generally unavoidable, but storing passwords is another story.